# Google Spreadsheets API - Conditional Formatting based on range and adjacent values

Tags: asp.net-core, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client, gs-conditional-formatting

I have the following very streamlined version of a spreadsheet:

```
Sect   | Lbl    | A      | B       | C       | D       | E
==========================================================
Sec1   | Lbl1   | 1      | 8       | 6       | 10      |
----------------------------------------------------------
Sec2   | Lbl2   | 2      | 1       | 1       | >100    |
----------------------------------------------------------
etc...
```

I want to apply a rule/rules across all values to say:

Bg Color = Green if:
 - the cell to the right is not blank and higher than this value

Bg Color = Red if: 
 - the cell to the right is not blank and less than this value

Bg Color = white (no action) if:
 - the cell to the right has the same value

In addition, if the value is set to the non-numeric ">100" I need to convert it to 100 as part of this formatting.

I'm using C# to do this with the Spreadsheets v4 API. 
So far I have the code below but I'm unsure as to how I could apply multiple conditions to a formatting rule.

## Update

*Please note updated table example above before reading below*

Thanks to TheMaster I've got something up and running but it's not quite right yet. I've got an additional factor of:

- the first row should be excluded from the conditional formatting
- the first two columns are labels and should also be ignored/excluded
- all other columns and rows of data need to be compared to the column to their right (if available) and coloured accordingly.

Here is my code so far for the `Red` rule (`where cell value > cell value to the right`). 
In addition to this I have a `Green` rule (`where cell value < cell value to the right`) and a `White` rule (`where cell value = cell value to the right`)

They are indexed as below in a batchupdate request:
0 = red
1 = green
2 = white

The Code for the `Red` rule:

```
formatRequest.Requests.Add(new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Request()
          {
              AddConditionalFormatRule = new AddConditionalFormatRuleRequest()
              {
                  Rule = new ConditionalFormatRule()
                  {
                      BooleanRule = new BooleanRule()
                      {
                          Condition = new BooleanCondition()
                          {
                              Type = "CUSTOM_FORMULA",
                              Values = new List<ConditionValue>() {
                                  new ConditionValue()
                                  {
                                      UserEnteredValue = "=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),(1*REGEXEXTRACT(A2,\"\\d+\"))>(1*REGEXEXTRACT(B2,\"\\d+\")))"
                                  }
                              }
                          },
                           Format = new CellFormat()
                           {
                               BackgroundColor = new Color()
                               {
                                   Red = 0.8f,
                                   Green = 0f,
                                   Blue = 0f,
                                   Alpha = 1f
                               }
                           }
                      },
                      Ranges =  new List<GridRange>()
                      {
                          new GridRange()
                          {
                              SheetId = Convert.ToInt32(sheetId)
                              ,StartRowIndex = 1
                          },
                      }
                   },
                  Index = 0
              }
          });
```

The problem is it doesn't apply the conditional formatting to the whole sheet...only the first column of data.

Comment: Review top voted questions in [tag:gs-conditional-formatting].

Comment: Default is white. You don't have to add white conditional formatting, unless you changed the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should use `CUSTOM_FORMULA` as Boolean condition Type
- You'll need to add two conditional formatting rules with `index` 0 and 1
- Range will be open-ended and cover the full sheet.

#### Snippet(for A1:Z;Bg:red):

- Boolean Condition JSON:

```
{ 
  "type": "CUSTOM_FORMULA",
  "values": [
    {
      userEnteredValue: "=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),A1>(IF(ISNUMBER(B1),B1,1*REGEXEXTRACT(B1,\"\d+\"))))"
    }
  ]
}
```

- BooleanRule/Format/BackgroundColor JSON:

```
{
  "red": 1,
  "green": 0,
  "blue": 0,
  "alpha": 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's got me further along but I'm struggling to get it to work exactly as I need. I've added some more info and examples above if you get chance to cast your learned eye over it!

Comment: I’ve tried using startColumnIndex but it didn’t seem to make a difference.

Comment: @scgough Try adding a `endRowIndex`. Can you show me how the conditional formatting looks in Sheets-screenshot? The `Apply to:` must be `C2:Z` and  the formula should reference the top left cell in that range, i.e., `C2`

Comment: Apply To: `C2:Z1000`
(steamlined) red formula: `=AND((1*REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"\d+"))<(1*REGEXEXTRACT(C2,"\d+")))`
This correctly formats the left newest column. However, if I add a new column to the LHS of the data (i.e. column C, D and E are now populated) the formatting is still only applied to the original column (now D). The new column data in C is unformatted.

Comment: @scgough  That should be a new question. However, that's to be expected, since the formatting originally applied to the original C column and not the new C column. You can try applying formatting from column B. This way, when you insert a new column between B and C, It's still in scope.

Comment: OK - I'll fire up a new question if that doesn't seem to work